Is it recommend adding schema.gql to .gitignore?
I found bifurcated concerns regarding schema.gql and version controlling. I have NestJS + GQL app, that is developed in code-first practice. The schema file is auto generated.
In many (unofficial) sources advice to keep that file in git so we can track changes. In other hand, checking github repos I found that people add schema.gql to their .gitignore file.
When deciding the correct approach, what factors should I consider and what are pros and cons of each above approach?

I think as a good practice you can keep the .gql schemas because it is part of the code, part of the application, that other developers can see and can study to understand the code.
In terms of security when you are deploying your application none of these files will be visible to the user. And if you are developing an application that exposes your API documentation, it is going to be natural that all the features of your .sql schemas can be seen in detail, such as the type you are declaring for each variable, which you can see with the Apollo Graphql Explorer.

I am in the same shebang and I strongly feel to git-ignore the schema.gql.
It is a generated file, and imo, you don't add generated files to git, right?
It is only bound to give a whole mess of conflicts on merge, pull and commits. And dev who wants to see the current schema can simply start the app and a new schema is generated.
Hoping for a sensible, knowledgeable answer here...
